# Algorithm for shortest path

Tags: path-finding

I have this maze of zeroes and ones.

```
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I can only walk to right if there is '1'. The objective is to start from left and finish on the rigth passing thought lines with '1' set on position and with the shortest path. In this example I select the lines 1, 10, 34 and 35 to accomplish the objective.

See only these lines selected.

```
01: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
10: 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
34: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
35: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

How can I solve this with an algorithm or a graph database?

Comment: **_I can only walk to right if there is '1'_** what are the valid move directions for `0` ?  The basic algorithm for a shortest path is [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Answer (score 0):

### Notation

- The number of columns is denoted by `n`.
- For a given row, `r`, the value on position `i` is denoted by `r[i]`.
- The set of all rows is denoted by `R`.

### Algorithm

```
  A := {{}}    # Set of sets of rows, initialized with the empty set of rows
  for i := 1, ..., n:
      for each S in A:
          If r[i]=0 for all r in S, then:     # True if S is the empty set.
              # The current position cannot be walked using the set S, so 
              # replace S with copies of S adding all rows with 1 on the
              # current position (i.e. possible solutions starting with S):
              A := A - S      # Remove S from A
              A := A + {S+{r} for all r in R where r[i]=1}
```

After this, the set `A` contains all the optimal solutions and possibly some suboptimal solutions. The sets in A with smallest cardinality are the optimal solutions.

In case there is no solution, `A`, will be the empty set.